# >>> & Оператор в СИ подобном коде

Tags: java

В новом для меня языке, известном в узких кругах и сделанном почти идентично Си, столкнулся с оператором >>> &. Сама строка выглядит вот так:

```
 new a = b >>> 4 & 15;
 new d = b & 488;
```

Хотелось бы узнать в каких источниках можно было бы поподробнее с этим ознакомиться.

Comment: Как верно отметил @harry - это два разных оператора. Вы сначала описываете его, как один оператор `>>> &`, а затем в исходном коде видно, что это таки два отдельных оператора. Я подозреваю, что такие же операторы есть и в C/C++.

Answer (score 7):

Вы же не пишете, что столкнулись с оператором `+-`, встретив запись

```
a = 5 + 6 - 2;
```

Так и здесь - в Java (к чему нам эти эвфемизмы?) оператор `>>>` - это 
сдвиг вправо с заполнением нулями, а `&` - побитовое И.

Приоритет `>>>` выше приоритета `&`, так что `b >>> 4 & 15` - это то же, что и `(b >>> 4) & 15`.

Прочитать - в любом учебнике по Java.